# Custom UITableViewCells not updating (prototype cell)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've seen several similar posts about Prototype cells not updating, and after attempting to follow through on a bunch of answers, I have to post a question of my own.  Like many, I have created a subclass of UITableViewCell and linked several properties to it's prototype cell in Xcode.

Custom Cell's .h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *playerNameLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *positionLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *playersPositionLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *teamLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *playersTeamLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *logoView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *layerView;
```

And in my ViewController file, I am using the following code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 PlayerTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"playerCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

 if ([self.playerSearchBar.text isEqualToString: @""]) {

     Player *player = self.playerArray[indexPath.row];

     cell.playerNameLabel.text = player.fullName;
     cell.playersPositionLabel.text = player.position;
     cell.playersTeamLabel.text = player.team;

 } else {

     Player *player = self.filteredPlayerArray[indexPath.row];

     cell.playerNameLabel.text = player.fullName;
     cell.playersPositionLabel.text = player.position;
     cell.playersTeamLabel.text = player.team;

 }
 return cell;
}
```

What's interesting is that the data is there, I can see it in the debugger, yet no labels update.  Previously I had done this with tags, but since I am making the design of the cells more complex, I have moved to subclassing.  Is there something I may be missing here?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Pj4E.png)

Comment: To be sure: have you linked outlets in interface builder?

Comment: Of course! Triple check that.

Comment: Have you registered your custom cell?

Comment: you must register your custom cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution for this is a bit inexplicable.  I deleted all of my IBOutlets and recreated them and reconnected them. Now, everything is working as it should have been.  For context, they were properly wired up to the storyboard prior to me deleting them.

Answer (score 0):

I think most probably you are missing this..

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"YourCustomCellNibName" bundle:nil]
 forCellReuseIdentifier:@"playerCell"];
```

In **tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:**, when we call dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:, if the table has no free reusable cell already in existence, the nib will automatically be loaded and the cell will be instantiated from it and returned to us.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to register your cell if you configured it inside the Storyboard. As seen in the Screenshot, the Cells being displayed properly so the registration process was successful. If you are using a nib it would crash if you forgot to register it, so this should not solve the Problem as suggested above.

The first thing that comes to my mind is that maybe the `playerArray` or the `filteredPlayArray` are not set, but then it would display rather nothing then the placeholder text. So i don't think this will solve your Problem. Anyway, try to check that. Have you also checked that `cell.playerNameLabel` is actually set to a non nil value ? 
If not, this could also be a Xcode Issue if all connection made properly. Try to restart Xcode and reconnect all the IBOutlets again.

Answer (score -1):

Always `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is returning the same cell. So please update your methods first line as below.

```
PlayerTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"playerCell"];
```

This may solve the problem. Assuming that you have proper `identifier` name in storyboard i.e playerCell

Comment: dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: is just older than dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:
Apple recommends to use newer version

Comment: FYI, Ofcourse apple may recommend , but as per the need what this guy have , there no any advantage of using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: .